# Как работает JDBC и ORM?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, jpa, orm

Прочитал достаточно много информации про JDBC и ORM, теперь хотел бы проверить свое понимание работы с БД в Java и задать пару вопросов касательно JDBC, JPA, ORM (Hibernate).

1. **JDBC** это интерфейс для работы с sql запросами в java.
2. **ORM** это тоже интерфейс который построен по спецификации JPA и у него есть несколько реализаций таких как Hibernate, EclipseLink и т.д. ORM работает по принципу мапинга объектов из Java к таблицам и их столбцам в БД, все это делает с  помощью анатаций, а запросы ORM составляет сама

Как я понял что JDBC, что ORM делают одно и тоже разница лишь сложности и оптимизации для разных проектов, то есть иногда выгодно использовать JDBC, а иногда ORM.

Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я рассуждаю?

Answer (score 0):

Нет неправильно рассуждаете.

JDBC это базис - ORM это надстройка над JDBC.

JDBC это гвозди которыми можно сколотить скажем табуретку, а ORM это автоматический пистолет, которым забивают гвозди.

Программист, который пишет на JDBC похож на трудягу который забивает гвозди ручным молотком, медленно и упорно. Если вы используете ORM, то уже похожи на квалифицированного рабочего который забивает гвозди пневмопистолетом: быстро и надежно.

Comment: Получается ORM упрощает работу с JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

JDBC - это средство работы с БД из java.
Hibernate (и jpa) - предназначен для отделения работы в java от работы в БД. При этом, программист работает в java, реализует бизнес-правила, а вопросы синхронизации с БД поручает Hibernate. Программист пишет на java, используя возвышенные абстракции ООП (в частности наследование), а hibernate, в соответствии с настройками и мапингом (который тоже может создать Hibernate) производит синхронизацию и подтягивание объектов по требованию. Предполагается, что программист не пишет запросов на select, insert, delete, update  (хотя такая возможность и предусмотрена) и SpringData еще больше усиливает эту возможность. Например, программист  в java запрашивает через hibernate объект по классу объекта и его id, изменяет поля этого объекта и после этого, запрашивает у hibernate синхронизацию этого объекта с БД. Hibernate сам понимает как написать select и как написать update.
Hibernate - это реляционное хранение (объектов java) под идеоматику java.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите пару тестовых проектов на [Spring Data JDBC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-jdbc/info) и на [Spring Data JPA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-data-jpa/info) - почувствуете разницу. По работе могут встретиться разные решения, требующие поддержки, но знать надо и то, и то.

`Spring Data JDBC` - сам управляешь обращениями к БД. Требуется знание `SQL`.

`Spring Data JPA` - упрощает обращения к БД средствами Java. Знание `SQL` не требуется, но может пригодиться.